# Get the Active Directory repeated service attribute from the exception details when creating a new user from VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, active-directory

I am working with an existing vb.net code that creates new users in Active Directory. The code works fine normally, but in some unknown circumstances it throws the error

> The specified directory service attribute or value already exists

How can I guess which service attribute already exists looking at the thrown exception?

I've tried to capture exception details, inner exception details (ex.ToString + ex.Message.xxx, etc.), stacktrace, exception.Data... But I was unable to guess that level of detail.

The code is as follows:

```
Try
Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry(myLocation)
Dim newUser As DirectoryEntry = dirEntry.Children.Add("cn=" & surnames + "\, " & name, "user")
newUser.Properties("displayName").Add(surnames & ", " & name)
newUser.Properties("name").Add(surnames & ", " & name)
newUser.Properties("sn").Add(surnames)
newUser.Properties("givenName").Add(name)
newUser.Properties("samAccountName").Add(userName)
newUser.Properties("userPrincipalName").Add(userName & domainAccountMail)
newUser.Properties("mailNickname").Add(userName)
newUser.Properties("mobile").Add(myTelephone)
newUser.Properties("mail").Add(myMail)
newUser.Properties("targetAddress").Add("SMTP:" & userName & CDomainMailCloudGeneral)
newUser.Properties("proxyAddresses").AddRange(New Object() {"SMTP:" & myMail, "smtp:" & userName & domainAcountMail, "smtp:" & userName & CDomainMailNubeGeneral})
newUser.Properties("userAccountControl").Value = &H2 Or &H200
newUser.CommitChanges()
Catch ex As Exception
```

As I'm writing this message, I'm thinking that the catch should be more specific for the exception type, but I don't know which one is it; Should I log ex.GetType().ToString to obtain it and then change the catch with the specific exception type, thus, obtaining that way more details ? Could it work ?

Thanks in advance,

Roger

Comment: Does another account with the same name already exist in that OU?

Comment: I don't have direct access to the windows Active Directory for security reasons; It's not possible. What I need as I mentioned in the main question, is a way to extract the details from the exception.

Comment: What does `ex.ToString()` show you?

Answer (score 0):

As you've observed, the exception may not provide enough detail to identify the source of the error.  Even if it did, you should not rely on try/catch for this.  Instead, add a check before each property assignment (this is C#, but if you need it converted to VB.NET let me know):

```
valueAlreadyExists = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GetAdPropertyValue(newUser, "sn"));

if (valueAlreadyExists)
{
    newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = surname;
}
else  // do an ADD operation
{
    newUser.Properties["sn"].Add(surname);
}
```

This approach would allow you to see which attribute/value already exists by adding a breakpoint or log statement under the condition(s) you want to check.

Here's the `GetAdPropertyValue` implementation:

```
private string GetAdPropertyValue(DirectoryEntry userAccount, string adPropertyKey)
{
    string result = null;
    PropertyValueCollection property = userAccount.Properties[adPropertyKey];

    if (property != null)
    {
        object propertyValue = property.Value;

        if (propertyValue != null)
        {
            string propertyValueString = (string)propertyValue;
            result = propertyValueString.Trim();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

While we're here, the other gotcha to be aware of is that AD can be finicky about where it expects nulls vs. empty strings if the value is blank.  This can be remedied as follows:

```
if (valueAlreadyExists)
{
    if (surname == "")  // assignment below wont accept empty strings, so convert it first
        surname = null;

    newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = surname;
}
else  // do an ADD operation
{
    if (surname == null)  // Add below wont accept nulls, so convert it first
        surname = "";

    newUser.Properties["sn"].Add(surname);
}
```

You'll probably want to wrap this code in a method instead of repeating it for each property.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tawab ! I'll give it a try next Monday... Seems a great workaround.